# The effect of default "line-height" is the same over all browsers?

Tags: html, css

Code:

```html
<div style="font-size:12px">abc</div>
```

On my chrome browser, the height of this div is 14px, which means the actual value of line-height of the div is 14px. How about on other browsers? Does W3C standard address this?

Comment: The default line height is `normal` which depends on browser, browser settings and font.

Comment: line-height is only one factor the define the height, you need to also consider alingment so height!=line-height

Comment: line-height is depends upon fonts you are using, its better to specify the line-height to get expected result in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The `line-height` for `div` elements defaults to a user agent value of `normal`. According to MDN, the interpretation of `normal` is user-agent dependent.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#values
> `normal` Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of roughly 1.2, depending on the element's font-family.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is `14.4px` height on firefox. On Safari it's `14px`.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height
`line-height:normal`
Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of roughly 1.2, depending on the element's font-family.

Also usefull: http://smad.jmu.edu/shen/webtype/lineheight.html

Answer (score -1):

I found one blog related to line-height with other height references in HTML/CSS.
[LINE-HEIGHT](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-tame-line-height-in-css/)

Hope this will help you to understand the concepts of line-height.